# XSLT add a parent node according to the grouped children value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, transformation

I'm new to XSLT and i'm trying to figure out how to add a parent node to group the data according to their childrens value. ( I'm not sure if that made sense but it's hard to explain.)

Here is the original output:

```
    <root>
    <detailRow>
        <EmployeeID>123456</EmployeeID>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <CompanyID>Cie_222</CompanyID>
    </detailRow>
    <detailRow>
        <EmployeeID>98765</EmployeeID>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <CompanyID>Cie_222</CompanyID>
    </detailRow>
    <detailRow>
        <EmployeeID>100859</EmployeeID>
        <LastName>Roe</LastName>
        <FirstName>Richard </FirstName>
        <CompanyID>Cie_227</CompanyID>
    </detailRow>    
</root>
```

I would like to have this output :

```
    <root>
    <GroupCompany id="Cie_222">
        <detailRow>
            <EmployeeID>123456</EmployeeID>
            <LastName>Doe</LastName>
            <FirstName>John</FirstName>
            <CompanyID>Cie_222</CompanyID>
        </detailRow>
        <detailRow>
            <EmployeeID>98765</EmployeeID>
            <LastName>Smith</LastName>
            <FirstName>John</FirstName>
            <CompanyID>Cie_222</CompanyID>
        </detailRow>
    </GroupCompany>

    <GroupCompany id="Cie_227">>        
    <detailRow>
        <EmployeeID>100859</EmployeeID>
        <LastName>Roe</LastName>
        <FirstName>Richard </FirstName>
        <CompanyID>Cie_227</CompanyID>
    </detailRow>
    </GroupCompany>     
</root>
```

currently i have this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="root/detailRow" group-by="CompanyID">
          <xsl:sort select="CompanyID"></xsl:sort>
          <xsl:copy>
              <GroupCompany id="CompanyID">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
              </GroupCompany>
          </xsl:copy>   
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </root>     
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grouping you have seems fine, only you don't need the `xsl:copy` but solely the `GroupCompany` wrapper and the population of the attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="root/detailRow" group-by="CompanyID">
          <xsl:sort select="CompanyID"></xsl:sort>
              <GroupCompany id="{current-grouping-key()}">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
              </GroupCompany>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </root>     
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, i tried your solution and for the attribute it's fine thanks however, it doesn't group properly. with my full code i only get two GroupCompany when there is more than 10. What could possibly do that ? note that the company can be empty. would that be the problem ?

Comment: Well, edit your question and show some sample input data and the corresponding result you want for empty company data.

Comment: It ended up working well. all it does now is an empty attribute for the company. I will accept your answer as this fit my need perfectly ! thanks !